# Ice Cream Sandwich; android:windowBackground behavior

Tags: themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, theming

I'm testing out my application for Android 2.2 on ICS. It work with ICS, but I have a weird problem.

I use a custom theme in my application, and I am using the android:windowBackground property to set a background image. It shows up nicely on Android 2.2-2.3 devices, but on ICS it adds some sort of weird white blending glow effect. It only happens if I set the android:windowBackground property.

This is the content of the windowBackground layout I use;

```
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tv_big"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center|top" />
```

If I do not set the android:windowBackground the problem is gone, and my application renders fine. I can't take a screenshot of the problem, because on screenshots the effect is not visible.

Has anyone encountered this problem? If so, what did you do?

Comment: have you found any solution of this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested in other devices?
Maybe,an emulator with lower or higher dpi ?
If it does not show on ScreenShot,it is probably something with the Screen.

Comment: No, no other devices. That was what I thought too, maybe it is the screen. I'll report back.

Comment: It may be a Layer that ICS puts on the top of your app,i don't know since im not codding for ICS yet.
Good luck,and let us know if you find out what it is